# Writing test cases for RxJava doOnSubscribe and doOnFinally situations

Tags: android, junit, mockito, rx-java

Let's say I've this particular piece of code in Kotlin. My question is how do I test during subscribing I have set the visibility of button to VISIBLE and set the text to "". And once subscription is completed I've made the visibility to GONE and test to "DONE".

```
fun getInfo() {
    getInfoFromApi()
        .doOnSubscribe {
            buttonVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE)
            buttonText.set(“”)
         }
        .onFinally {
            buttonVisibility(View.GONE)
            buttonText.set(“DONE”)
        }
        .subscribe {
            // Some other random stuff
        }
    }
}
```

As of now my test cases look like this.

```
@Test
fun getInfo() {
    viewModel.getInfo()
    Assert.assertEquals(View.GONE, viewModel.buttonVisibility.get())
    Assert.assertEquals(“DONE”, viewModel.buttonText.get())
}
```

Which obviously is correct when you look at what the final state should be, but how do I test the intermediate stages of doOnSubscribe?

Is there a way to Assert, if the button text was set to DONE from "", and visibility went from VISIBLE to GONE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doOnSubscribe` and `onFinally` are just states of your `View`/`ViewModel`, so you can extract these states and check state changes:

```
fun getInfo() {
    getInfoFromApi()
        .doOnSubscribe {
            view.setButtonVisible()
         }
        .onFinally {
            view.setButtonGone()
        }
        .subscribe {
            // Some other random stuff
        }
    }
}
```

And then verify calls:

```
@Test
fun getInfo() {
    val view = mock(View::class)
    viewModel.getInfo()
    verify(view, times(1)).setButtonVisible())
    verify(view, times(1)).setButtonGone())
}
```

By the way, if your example supposed to be used with `MVVM` then your `ViewModel` should not have reference to `View`. `ViewModel` should provide bindings for view. And then code could look like this:

```
fun getInfo():Observable<State> {
    return concat(
       just(State.Progress), 
       getInfoFromApi().map(State.Result)
    ).onErrorResumeNext(just(State.Error))
}
```

And then tests became even more abstract and clear

```
@Test
fun getInfoSuccess() {
    //config api success behaviour
    TestObserver<State> observer = TestObserver.create();
    viewModel.getInfo().subscribe(observer)
    observer.assertResult(State.Progress, State.Result);
}

@Test
fun getInfoError() {
    //config api error behaviour
    TestObserver<State> observer = TestObserver.create();
    viewModel.getInfo().subscribe(observer)
    observer.assertResult(State.Progress, State.Error);
}
```